# Querying named graphs and different SPARQL endpoints

Tags: sparql, jena, named-graphs

I am quite new to SPARQL so bear with me, please. I am using Apache Jena to store my RDFs in different named graphs, I have these RDF named graphs:

Endpoint Name:`http://localhost:3030/2012-2013/query`

Named Graphs:

```
<http://localhost:3030/2012-2013/data/2012-2013_62DAYBYCANCER>
<http://localhost:3030/2012-2013/data/2012-2013_62_DAY_CANCER_PLAN_ALL_CANCER>
<http://localhost:3030/2012-2013/data/2012-2013_62_DAY_CRS_SCEENING>
```

In another endpoint I have these named graphs:

Endpoint Name :
`http://localhost:3030/2013-2014/query`

Named Graphs:

```
<http://localhost:3030/2013-2014/data/2013-2014_62DAYBYCANCER>
<http://localhost:3030/2013-2014/data/2013-2014_62_DAY_CANCER_PLAN_ALL_CANCER>
<http://localhost:3030/2013-2014/data/2013-2014_62_DAY_CRS_SCEENING>
```

I would like to access the triples in the graph `2012-2013_62DAYBYCANCER` and joining them to triples from `2013-2014_62DAYBYCANCER`. Is it possible to use named graphs and service together?

The structure of the graphs is given below. I would like to join them with the `provider` and the `period-type` to get the `total`.

For the graph `2012-2013_62DAYBYCANCER` the structure is:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://mastersrdf.org/dataset/2012_2013_62DAYBYCANCER/1"> 
    <qb:dataSet rdf:resource="http://mastersrdf.org/dataset/2012_2013_62DAYBYCANCER"/>
    <provider xmlns="http://mastersrdf.org/def/statistical-dimension/" rdf:resource="http://mastersrdf.org/hull-and-east-yorkshire-hospitals-nhs-trust"/>
    <total xmlns="http://mastersrdf.org/def/statistical-dimension/">4</total>
    <period-type xmlns="http://mastersrdf.org/def/statistical-dimension/" rdf:resource="http://mastersrdf.org/q1"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

For the graph `2013-2014_62DAYBYCANCER` the structure is:

```xml
<rdf:Description rdf:about="http://mastersrdf.org/dataset/2013_2014_62DAYBYCANCER/1"> 
    <qb:dataSet rdf:resource="http://mastersrdf.org/dataset/2013_2014_62DAYBYCANCER"/>
    <provider xmlns="http://mastersrdf.org/def/statistical-dimension/" rdf:resource="http://mastersrdf.org/hull-and-east-yorkshire-hospitals-nhs-trust"/>
    <total xmlns="http://mastersrdf.org/def/statistical-dimension/">50</total>
    <period-type xmlns="http://mastersrdf.org/def/statistical-dimension/" rdf:resource="http://mastersrdf.org/q1"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: `<http://localhost:3030/2012-2013/data/2013-2014_62DAYBYCANCER>` - mistype? `2012-2013`...`2013-2014`.

Comment: yes sorry about that changed from 2012-2013 to 2013-2014 thank you

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use named graphs and service together?

Yes.  The pattern in the `SERVICE` clause will need to include a `GRAPH` clause.  (The desired result will not be obtained by the `SERVICE` clause being inside a `GRAPH` clause.)

Comment: I am quite new to sparql is it possible to provide an example I could follow, please?